# delete given task from listview android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-intent, android-listview

a rookie in android.Have a bit of situation in here as of what's going on with the application as log cat gives a null pointer exception.
the flow of application is as such ;a given [title and notes] is got through intent from listview_activity on to a different layout ;where on clicking delete button should delete 
the given data form database and close the current activity and come back to list_activity

```
package com.example.tasklist;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DisplayTask extends Activity {

TextView TiTv, Latv;
Button btnEdit, btnDelete;

List<Task> ntsk;
private static int position;

final Task tkks = ntsk.get(position);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.title_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    TiTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TitleTV);
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("etra1");
    TiTv.setText(title);

    Latv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NotesTV);
    String task = intent.getStringExtra("etra2");
    Latv.setText(task);

    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DeleteBtn);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DbHandler dbht = new DbHandler(DisplayTask.this);
            dbht.DeleteTask(tkks);

            Toast.makeText(DisplayTask.this, tkks.getTitle() + "Deleted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `null pointer exception` => post stacktrace.

Comment: `close the current activity` => `finish()`